# How to approximate $\text{li}(z)$ numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, approximation

I'm trying to implement a function to calculate $\pi(x)$ via Riemann's formula:
$$
\pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x} ,
$$
with $    \operatorname{R}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})$, the sum runs over the non-trivial roots of $\zeta$ and $\text{li}(z)$ being the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

The problem is that I don't have function to calculate $\text{li}(z)$.
Since I'm not familiar with complex limits I'm not sure if I can write it as a simple sum.

Thanks for your help,

**BTW**, my result for $x=100,n_{max}=1$ and only one root of $\zeta$ is $30.2748$. Can anyone crosscheck that?

Comment: Can't you use the exponentially converging series by Ramanuajan mentioned in the article to approximate li$(x)$?

Comment: I guess, you only need it for real $x$?

Comment: @Marvis No $z=x^{1/2 + it_k}$...

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't see you wanted $R(x^{\rho})$.

Comment: I should have an idea about this from your stated purpose, but how accurately do you need to compute this?

Comment: @rlgordonma let's say the steps in the approximation should be visible. Is that enough?

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/efficiently-calculating-the-logarithmic-integral-with-complex-argument) helpful?

Comment: @Argon not sure maybe I'll take this one: $\mathrm{E_1}(z)=\frac{\exp(-z)}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{n!}{(-z)^n} $ from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Asymptotic_.28divergent.29_series). And then $\text{li}(z)=E_1(\ln(z))$ What do you think?

Comment: @Marvis what would you think about using $
    \mathrm{E_1}(z)=\frac{\exp(-z)}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{n!}{(-z)^n} $? And then $\text{li}(z)=E_1(\ln(z))$

Comment: Doesn't $\textrm{li}(x^{1/n})$ diverge as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @user7530 true: The function $1/\ln(t)$ has a singularity at t = 1...

Comment: See J.M.'s answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/efficiently-calculating-the-logarithmic-integral-with-complex-argument) : I too recommend using $\operatorname{Ei}$ (or $\operatorname{E1}$) as well as the continued fraction (rather than series that may require too much precision and time!). Remember too writing $\operatorname{Ei}(\rho\ln(x))$ and not $\operatorname{Ei}(\ln(x^{\rho}))$ (important for large imaginary part!).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni ok I'll give that a try.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni "Continued fractions" work perfectly. Thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found this very nice paper:

> $\phantom{somespace}$[On the Evaluation of the Complex-ValuedExponential Integral](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~vpegorar/research/2011_JGT/paper.pdf)
>
> by Vincent Pegoraro and Philipp Slusallek
>   Saarland University:
>
> **Abstract**. Although its applications span a broad scope of scientific fields ranging
>   from applied physics to computer graphics, the exponential integral is a nonelementary
>   special function available in specialized software packages but not in standard
>   libraries, consequently requiring custom implementations on most platforms. In
>   this paper, we provide a concise and comprehensive description of how to evaluate
>   the complex-valued exponential integral. We first introduce some theoretical background
>   on the main characteristics of the function, and outline available third-party
>   proprietary implementations. We then provide an analysis of the various known
>   representations of the function and present an effective algorithm allowing the computation
>   of results within a desired accuracy, together with the corresponding pseudocode
>   in order to facilitate portability onto various systems. An application to
>   the calculation of the closed-form solution to single light scattering in homogeneous
>   participating media illustrates the practical benefits of the provided implementation
>   with the hope that, in the long term, the latter will contribute to standardizing the
>   availability of the complex-valued exponential integral on graphics platforms.
>   CCS: G.1.2 [Numerical Analysis]: Approximation – Special function approximations

They put pseudocodes for all approximations there, which are really close to an implementation.